# finding same parts of strings values in SQL

Tags: sql

Can I find same parts of strings values in SQL?
Also this parts should be more then one character.
For example in in column with values

```
good table
excellent book
nice table
bad chair
nice magazine
```

It should find `table` and `nice`.
I'm not sure maybe `Like` + Regex can help with it.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, a tag for the database you are using and a clear explanation.

Comment: `Like` would be completely enough.

Comment: Do you know upfront what parts you are looking for? For instance do you know that you are looking for "table" specifically, or are you looking for re-occuring patterns

Comment: I understood thet explain task incorrect, so other example or this: if i have colums of emails and i want count their domains, like 'blabla@gmail.com' 'agadga@hotmail.com' 'asgdgd@gmail.com' 'agaga@mail.net', 'dga@gmail.com', 'dgagg1s@gmail.com', 'dgadd1s@gmail.com', 'agadgdda@hotmail.com', 'agag@mail.net'
and i want result table like 
'@gmail.com' 5
'@hotmail.com' 2
'@mail.net' 2

Answer (score 1):

Please, read my comment to the question.

Try this:

```
SELECT Column1
FROM YourTable
WHERE Column1 Like '%table%' OR Column1 Like '%nice%'
```

This should return: `good table`, `nice table`, `nice magazine`

More: [SQL Like Operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)